# Creating array in array from foreach in foreach xml values

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

iv spent 3 days for lurking google, and i can create array in array from few xmls (every xml has one day) but this second array has three dots instead values and tried a lot of things. Let me show you some code.
One eg. XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
<info>
  <item ID="NAMEOFFILE" DATA="2020-11-02" HOUR="22:01" USER="XXXX" ></item>
</info>
<transaction>
  <item VALUE="5" DESC="User 1"></item>
  <item VALUE="1.22" DESC="User 2"></item>
  <item VALUE="9.37" DESC="User 3"></item>
</transaction>
</data>
```

And php code:

```
    $xml  = array();
    foreach ($xml_files as $f) 
    {  
       $content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($f)); 
       $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
       
       $arrayName = array(); 
       foreach ($data->transaction->item as $values) 
       {  
          //$arrayName[] = trim($values['VALUE']); //this works but i want to add array VALUE with DESC
          $arrayName[] = array('val' => (double)trim($values['VALUE']), 'desc' => trim($values['DESC']));
       }
       $xml[] = array(
          'fileName' => trim($data->info->item['ID']) 
          ,'data' => trim($data->info->item['DATA'])
          ,'hour' => trim($data->info->item['HOUR'])  
          ,'user' => trim($data->info->item['USER'])
          ,'transaction' => $arrayName
                        
       );  
    }
var_dump($xml);
```

The best i achieved is:

```
array (size=16)
  'fileName' => string 'NAMEOFFILE' (length=8)
  'data' => string '2020-12-01' (length=10)
  'hour' => string '13:50' (length=5)
  'user' => string 'XXXXX' (length=16)
  'transaction' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
```

or

```
// with $arrayName[] = trim($values['VALUE']);
array (size=16)
  'fileName' => string 'NAMEOFFILE' (length=8)
  'data' => string '2020-12-01' (length=10)
  'hour' => string '13:50' (length=5)
  'user' => string 'XXXXX' (length=16)
  'transaction' => 
    array (size=3)
        array (size=7)
          0 => float 5
          1 => float 1.22
          2 => float 9.37
```

i simply want to achieve this second array as

```
 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'VALUE' => float 5
      'DESC' => string 'descripton value 1' (length=30)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'VALUE' => float -2.22
      'DESC' => string 'description value 2' (length=30)
```

iv tried with array_psuh, merge, add... tried to even do $arrName[][] and diffrent variations, tried to put all arrays elements to add in every place inside, oustside foreach any loops etc. I can bet that it's ridiculous error, but when i was lurking for "creating array in array php" and similar in google, they always show how to read arrays or create simple one without any double foreach etc. Somebody could help? ;/

Comment: Side note: are you **totally sure** that you want to run `utf8_encode`? It is really badly named, and is often mistaken for a magic "fix all my UTF-8 issues", when all it actually does is convert from one specific single-byte encoding ("ISO LATIN 1") to UTF-8. If your input is not in that specific single-byte encoding, all it will do is mangle your data.

Comment: As for your actual question, I think that `...` is just the output of your debugging function. Although you show `var_dump`, your output isn't from the built-in `var_dump`, which would look like this: https://3v4l.org/nhG7N (note for instance how it says `array(2)` not `array (size=2)`).

Comment: @IMSoP oh my... you are absoluteley right!! 
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);` 
do the job... my 3 days of mixing code becouse of bad output! I did it right for first time :D